# Coverting a python list into string with comma separated in efficient way

Tags: python

I have a list of acc nos:

```
list1 = ['1234','3456','2345','5543','1344','5679','6433','3243','0089']
```

Output I need is a string:

`print(output)`: `'1234','3456','2345','5543','1344','5679','6433','3243','0089'`

Comment: Is this an XY problem? ie, are you trying to write a csv file?

Comment: What you tried so far and why it did not work?

Comment: No, I have a created a list from a csv file by reading the file via pandas. Want to convert that into required format s said above

Comment: `str(list1).strip('[]')` does what you want, but are you sure you really want this? Seems particularly useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = ['1234','3456','2345','5543','1344','5679','6433','3243','0089']
>>> print(','.join(["'{0}'".format(s) for s in list1]))
'1234','3456','2345','5543','1344','5679','6433','3243','0089'
```

Comment: Or with a current version of Python: `print(','.join([f"'{s}'" for s in list1]))`

Answer (score 3):

You can join all the values with `','` and then adding a `'` before and after the string like this:

```py
"'{0}'".format("','".join(list1))
```